# How to make int's from script 1 shared with script 2 3 etc

Tags: python, mysql

I am making a program that pulls information (ip adres/ cycel times ect) out of mysql to my python script.

This script will then one by one call 3 other scripts that will be in need of that infomation from mysql to function.

question 1
    how can i call and run those 3 other scripts from script 1 (and if needed make them pass on there newly created data back to script 1)

question 2
    and how can i best supply the information from script 1 to them without altering the 3 other scripts drastically?

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far? But in general I would say use classes and objects http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/OOP.shtml

Comment: import the script to ur intial script and call the methods of that script

Comment: use functions instead of scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @alexvassel and think that instead of scripts, these should be functions within a single `.py` file. However, if this is unfeasable, you can use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to call the other scripts with the values they need as command line arguments. Then use can use the [argparse module](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) to easily parse those arguments.

Quick example:

```
import subprocess

ip = '127.0.0.1'
cycle_time = 42
subprocess.call(['./other_script.py', '--ips={} --cycletime={}'.format(ip, cycle_time)])
```